# how to set input parameter in select query of anypoint

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule-esb, mulesoft

how to set input parameter in select query on anypoint-stutio

i'm newer on anypoint studio. and i'm tring to get some data from database . but i don't know how to set input parameter in anypoint. 
may i know who can provide some guides or cookbook for this.

[image]

for example: 
my query is "select * from  ESPOSSG.xf_salesimport where xf_txdate=:xf_txdate "

i need to set input parameters in anypoint 
the i can use "http://localhost:10256/sales/txdate='20190601'" to get data

Answer (score 0):

Your Input parameters should be like Dataweave expression, instead you have used expression to print logger.

Try this Instead:

```
{
  xf_txdate:message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.txdate
}
```